# Android - How can I do an animation that changes other views while scrolling a list view?

Tags: android, animation

In the picture below, the left screen shows the starting state of the animation and the right screen shows the ending state.

What the animation does is that while the list view is being moved from top to bottom, the Welcome label will gradually move up, and the profile image view will gradually scale smaller and move to the top right corner.
When the list view is being moved back to the top, the reversed animation will happen.

I would like to ask how I can do that?
The picture about the starting and ending states of the animation

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you struggling? Adding your code will make it easy to help

Comment: study about shared transitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this transition , It might not be perfect you might have to fix a little bit

Take 2 imageviews starting an ending of animation . make ending animation imageview Invisible

```
 scrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChanged() {
            int scrollY = scrollView.getScrollY();

           interpolate(start_profile_imageView, end_profile_imageView, scrollY );

        }
    });
```

Add these in the same class

```
private RectF mRect1 = new RectF();
private RectF mRect2 = new RectF();

private void interpolate(View view1, View view2, float interpolation) {
    getOnScreenRect(mRect1, view1);
    getOnScreenRect(mRect2, view2);

    float scaleX = 1.0F + interpolation * (mRect2.width() / mRect1.width() - 1.0F);
    float scaleY = 1.0F + interpolation * (mRect2.height() / mRect1.height() - 1.0F);
    float translationX = 0.5F * (interpolation * (mRect2.left + mRect2.right - mRect1.left - mRect1.right));
    float translationY = 0.5F * (interpolation * (mRect2.top + mRect2.bottom - mRect1.top - mRect1.bottom));

    view1.setTranslationX(translationX);
    view1.setTranslationY(translationY);
    view1.setScaleX(scaleX);
    view1.setScaleY(scaleY);

}

private RectF getOnScreenRect(RectF rect, View view) {
    rect.set(view.getLeft(), view.getTop(), view.getRight(), view.getBottom());
    return rect;
}
```

Also check out this [project](https://github.com/flavienlaurent/NotBoringActionBar)

Comment: Thank you so much. Your solution really helped me.